# How to join three MySQL tables with unrelated data?

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a webpage that shows an image and information about it, and I also have three tables.

```
IMAGES                             USERS                        COMMENTS
id                                 user_id                      id
user_id                            username                     user_id
username                           password                     comment
title                              isadmin                      date
image (location)                   points
description                        signup_date
points                             email
category                           city
                                   bio
                                   profile_image
```

I need to use all the information from the images and comments table. But I also need to retrieve the profile_image of the user that posted the comment and image. I cannot figure out how to do this: here is what I have so far.

```
$conn = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project", "root", "pass");
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
SELECT images.*, users.profile_image, comments.* 
FROM (images.id JOIN comments ON images.id = comments.id) 
LEFT JOIN users 
ON images.user_id = user.profile_image
");
```

Am I close? or trying the impossible here!?

Comment: so your goal is to get all the comments with the its users information and image?

Comment: If you ask me I'd get the comments with a new query. 1st query gets the image + user data 2nd query gets comments and user data

Comment: I don't think the three tables are unrelated completely; certainly the user's ID appears in every table.  But it's not clear to me how we relate comments to the other two tables.  It almost seems as if a foreign key is missing somewhere.

Comment: Are you trying to say the following?

1>A user logs in and sees the image he has uploaded
2>Now the user wants to check the comments he received from other users which can be an image or a text?
3>The comments on the image are linear in fashion, and does not follow a tree pattern of commenting

Could you please confirm this?

Comment: @Beginner Yeah I need all of the images info, all of the comments and then I need to link in the users profile image so it can be displayed next to their comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a lot simpler then you'd think :)

the tables are NOT unrelated, they all have the same key - `user_id` and that's how you join them.

your query should look like this:

```
SELECT images.*, users.profile_image, comments.* 
FROM images 
JOIN users ON images.user_id = users.user_id
JOIN comments ON comments.user_id = users.user_id AND images.id = comments.id
```

this is assuming the `images.id` and `comments.id` match (I suspect they do not - but you did not give us enough info)

looking at your table structure, comments and images appear to have no connection, so maybe query them separately to avoid duplicated & confusing data

**---UPDATE---**

assuming you've added `image_id` to `comments` this is your query:

```
SELECT images.*, users.profile_image, comments.* 
FROM images 
LEFT JOIN users ON images.user_id = users.user_id
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.user_id = users.user_id AND images.id = comments.image_id
```

what LEFT JOIN does is return 'images' that don't necessarily have 'users' or 'comments' connected to them.

Comment: Apologies on the lack of info, would adding a column named image_id be linkable to the id from images? This would then mean that the ids match but under a different name

Comment: If you can add the `image_id` of the image the comment matches - that's perfect and you can write one clean query

Comment: I think I'm confusing myself here, so I should add an image_id to the comments table. Would I then need to add image_id to the images table as well, so that I can join them? Or can I just link the id from images to image_id in comments?

Comment: if a comment is directly linked to an image, you save the image id (`images.id`) into the comment so they are connected (each comment is connected to an image, an image can have multiple comments connected to it - that is called a 1:n (1 to n) connection) and then you can query both image and it's comments together

Comment: take a look at the updated query I've written in the answer

Comment: I've added it to my code but I'm just getting a white page, no errors. I'm trying to use it in a php statement, can update question to show you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143613/discussion-between-alex-dudley-and-jameson-the-dog).

Comment: In order for this to work for me I had to add LEFT before each JOIN, this fixes a white screen issue for me.

Comment: that's great! `LEFT JOIN` changes the query a bit, it will now return all images, even if not connected to users or comments. I think it's what you need but you do need to know that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will do the trick:

```
SELECT i.*, u.profile_image, c.* 
FROM images i
LEFT JOIN comments c ON i.user_id = c.user_id 
LEFT JOIN users u ON i.user_id = u.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's:

```
>   SELECT  images.*, users.profile_image, comments.* 
>       FROM images
>      INNER JOIN users ON images.user_id= users.user_id
>      INNER JOIN comments ON users.user_id= comments.user_id
```